# SQL select latest created datetime if updated datetime duplicate

Tags: sql

I would like to select TAG in condition:

- if the latest `updated_datetime` is `NULL`, select `created_datetime`
- select latest `created_datetime` if `updated_datetime` are duplicate

MY_TABLE

```
ID       updated_datetime     created_datetime       TAG
---------------------------------------------------------
2021095         null         2021-09-20 15:05:26     A
2021095         null         2021-09-21 15:05:26     A
2021096 2021-11-23 01:34:57  2021-09-20 15:05:26     B
2021096 2021-11-23 01:34:57  2021-11-23 01:27:15     B
2021096 2021-11-23 01:34:57  2021-11-23 01:34:57     B
```

Expected output:

```
ID       latest_datetime        FLAG
------------------------------------
2021095  2021-09-21 15:05:26     Y
2021096  2021-11-23 01:34:57     N
```

Can I use `PARTITION BY` for `latest_datetime`?

Please help me how can I write the code?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple aggregation by the ID should do it

```
SELECT 
  ID
, MAX(COALESCE(latest_datetime, created_datetime)) AS latest_datetime
, MAX(CASE WHEN TAG = 'A' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS FLAG
FROM MY_TABLE t
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: brilliant but why do we need max function for case when tag... line?

Comment: Because it's currently only grouping by the ID. In standard sql, any field that's not in a function like MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG,... must also be in the GROUP BY.